# How do I merge objects within array in JMESPath?

Tags: jmespath

How can I merge objects within array?

```json
{
  "input": [
    {
      "company_name": "Test",
      "property_space": 151821
    },
    {
      "company_name": "Test",
      "property_space": 145236
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get an output like this

```json
{
  "output": [
    {
      "company_name": "Test",
      "property_space": 297057
    }               
  ]
}
```

Comment: I fear your example is over simplified. Are your expecting to have a `group by` like in SQL?

Comment: Or are you going to have only one company in your input and just what to sum the `property_space`?

Comment: Yes  One company_name and property_space should be sum

Answer (score 0):

*Mind that there is no proper grouping capacity build in JMESPath at the moment, although there is a proposition to offer one in a fork of the official repository. <sup>[reference](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.jep/issues/7)</sup>*

---

But, if what you want to achieve is *just* to sum the `property_space` properties, then a way to do it would be:

```
{  
  "output": [
    {
      company_name: input[0].company_name, 
      property_space: sum(input[].property_space)
    }
  ]
}
```

Which, on your example JSON would indeed give you the expected

```json
{
  "output": [
    {
      "company_name": "Test",
      "property_space": 297057
    }
  ]
}
```